# In-App Purchase - Consumable Items Dilemma

Tags: iphone

I've read everything I've found on in-app purchase and don't know whats the best way to go in order to do the following:

I have an app I'm developing and want to set two paid options + 1 free option in order to access sample content and paid content.

I'd like to offer a paid 24 hour access and I've read this goes against apples TOS. (sorry but cant find the doc now). Says something like they wont allow apps that recognize and restrict content for specific amount of time.

Wondering if creating two consumable items

1. One Year membership Item
2. One day access item

Could be a good option and if doing this would be OK with Apple's TOS.
Apple's docs about consumables only talk about games, such as weapons, food, levels.....

Feel free to comment and suggest other ways to accomplish what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought of subscriptions, but I think the shortest subscription term is a week.

Comment: Subscriptions seem to be available only to newsstand apps such as magazines and newspapers. Think of going for one option to buy the app in full and still trying to figure our how to do the one day access. Thinking of setting it up as above , like a test to try out the content but the problem i see is if i give users access and then they close the app for whatever reason ( if theres no 24h check ) then they will have no access, and that could annoy users..... any idea is welcome. thanks.